# regex to get multiple number after cretin characters

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this text

```
transaction A2999 num 111 from b123 c 6666666 t d 7777
```

i need to get numbers after `c` and `t d` (pleas mind the spaces before and after characters ) which are `6666666` and `7777` 
i've tried

```
 str.match(/\ c (\d+)/);
```

which gives me

```
Array(2)
0: " c 6666666"
1: "6666666"
```

i guess i can run the same regex twice for each number and grab the last col in the array but im not sure its the cleanest way to go ... seems pretty noobish to me (and im one when it comes to regex )

Comment: You need `[ ](?:c|t d) +(\d+)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d+)\st\sd\s(\d+)$
```

```js
var text = "transaction A2999 num 111 from b123 c 6666666 t d 7777"
var regex = /(\d+)\st\sd\s(\d+)$/

matches = text.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
// matches[1] = 6666666 
// matches[2] = 7777
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex and capture group 1 and group 2.

```
^.*\s+c\s+(\d+)\s+(?:t\s+d)\s+(\d+)$
```

Play with regex here,

https://regex101.com/r/Ww9ZaR/1

Answer (score 1):

Change `c` in the regex to `(?:c|t d)` resulting in the regex `/ (?:c|t d) (\d+)/`.

The `(?:...)` is the same as a normal group `(...)` but doesn't capture the result. Therefore this group is also called the [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

I've also set the global flag (`g`) for the regex to allow multiple matches in one string. This is also needed to avoid an infinite loop while using the [RegExp *exec* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in a *while* statement.

```js
var str = 'transaction A2999 num 111 from b123 c 6666666 t d 7777',
    regexp = /\ (?:c|t d) (\d+)/g,
    match;
    
while (match = regexp.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
str.match(/\ [cd] (\d+)/);
```